# Leaf and self loop

Tags: nodes, graph-theory, vertex

Can a node with a self-loop be a leaf node? Or maybe leaf is defined only for simple graphs (no self-loop, no multiple edges)? I can't find the answer. I found various definitions, but nowhere an answer for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A graph with a loop isn't a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) but a graph with a cycle. Leaves are defined for trees only.

Let's take a more formal approach. A self-loop adds 2 to the degree of a vertex, or 1 to both indegree and outdegree in case of directed graphs. Assuming that a leaf is a vertex with outdegree 0 (and indegree 1, but that's guaranteed by a definition of a tree), a vertex with a self-loop cannot be a leaf.

Comment: Thanks. I know it's mostly used with trees, but I'm implementing an "isCyclic" algorithm where obviously I try to check if a graph is cyclic ( http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~keller/courses/cs60/s98/examples/acyclic/ ). And in that case it hasn't got to be a tree.